# Convert chararacter numbers to numeric in nested list with mixed types in R

Tags: r, iteration, nested-lists, type-coercion

I have a bunch of nested lists that arrive with all character-typed elements. Some of these characters are in fact numbers that need to be converted to numeric-typed elements.

How can I modify these lists so that all possible character-typed numbers are converted to numeric, but the non-number character elements remain intact (e.g., aren't converted to `NA` by `as.numeric()`)?

For example, I start with

```
raw_list <- list(
      'a' = list('1', '2'),
      'b' = list(
        'c' = list('3', 'x'),
        'd' = c('4', 'z'),
        'e' = '5'))
```

But I need to get to

```
cleaned_list <- list(
      'a' = list(1, 2),
      'b' = list(
        'c' = list(3, 'x'),
        'd' = c('4', 'z'),
        'e' = 5))
```

**Bonus:** Extra gratitudie for tidyverse/purrr-based solutions

Comment: Shouldn't `e` be 5 in `raw_list`?

Comment: You're right, I've changed the input and output so they match

Comment: I don't understand. Is there something I should do with this link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option is to use `type.convert`, which can take lists as arguments.

```
raw_list %>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
```

This would be the same as using `purrr` with `type.convert`.

```
library(purrr)

purrr::map(raw_list, type.convert, as.is = TRUE)
```

Output

```
$a
$a[[1]]
[1] 1

$a[[2]]
[1] 2


$b
$b$c
$b$c[[1]]
[1] 3

$b$c[[2]]
[1] "x"


$b$d
[1] "4" "z"

$b$e
[1] 5
```

Comment: You don't need `purrr` in this case. `type.convert()` can take lists as argument. So: `raw_list %>% 
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE)` is the same as with `purrr`.

Comment: Note that tjis solution still keeps the 4 in element d as character.

Comment: @deschen. Also does the `map` solution. `$d
[1] "4" "z"` must be character according to the rules of atomic vectors?! Or am I missing something?

Comment: Right. Didn‘t pay close enough attention. You can‘t have character and numbers in one vector.

Comment: You're all correct that in `'d' = c('4', 'z')`, the number 4 must remain a character because its part of an atomic vector. I've revised the question and the `cleaned_list` output to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `readr::parse_guess` to convert character-typed numbers to numeric-typed numbers without converting characters to `NA`s.

I also created a function to convert the numbers in a nested list.
Please note that you cannot store characters and numerics in the same vector.

I hope this would help you.

```r
library(tidyverse)
func_parse_list <- function(l){
  if(length(l)>1){
    map(l, func_parse_list) %>% return()
  }else{
    parse_guess(l) %>% return()
  }
}
list('a' = list('1', '2'),
     'b' = list(
       'c' = list('3', 'x'),
       'd' = c('4', 'z'),
       'e' = '5')) %>%
  func_parse_list()
#> $a
#> $a[[1]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $a[[2]]
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> 
#> $b
#> $b$c
#> $b$c[[1]]
#> [1] 3
#> 
#> $b$c[[2]]
#> [1] "x"
#> 
#> 
#> $b$d
#> $b$d[[1]]
#> [1] 4
#> 
#> $b$d[[2]]
#> [1] "z"
#> 
#> 
#> $b$e
#> [1] 5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>